# MapView under statusbar with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-statusbar

I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abl_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ctl_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
                map:cameraZoom="15"
                map:liteMode="true"
                map:mapType="normal"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_pin"
        style="@style/FabStyle"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/abl_header"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I would like to have the MapView (fragment here) draw below the status bar as on the picture below:
[image: Expected result]

But instead I have the following result:
[image: Not working result]

But when scrolling, the MapView is correctly drawn below the status bar as shown on the picture below:
[image: MapView drawn below when scrolling]

And because, this is working when using an ImageView instead of the fragment, I am guessing this is because of a wrong measurement when the fragment is being build.

I would like to know if there is other solution than creating the MapView and creating the Bitmap from the code before injecting the bitmap in an ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out how to solve this.

Instead of creating the MapView fragment from the layout file itself.
I create the SupportMapFragment and add it to the view using classic Fragment transaction.

In that way, I have a correct rendering.